# php arrays have same keys, merge and rearrange keys in one array

Tags: php, arrays

I has array when i use `var_dump` function to print array show me the below result

```
var_dump($val);
```

the result is

```
array (size=1)
0 => string '6' (length=1)

array (size=1)
0 => string '6' (length=1)

array (size=1)
0 => string '4' (length=1)
```

as see the `$val` contains three different array that have the zero index key

how i can merge them in one array and change or rearrange the zero index to `0`, `1` and `2`

**EDITED**

for more information when i use `print_r($val)` the result as below

```
Array ( [0] => 6 ) Array ( [0] => 6 ) Array ( [0] => 4 )
```

but the number of array in `$val` various not every time ins three arrays would be 4 array or 5 array etc..

how i can merge all in one array and index of them?

Comment: Wait, one `var_dump` is printing this? Or is it correct to assume that you have something like this: `$val = array(array('foo'), array('bar'), array('something'));`? Can you post the **exact** structure of `$val`?

Comment: Does not look like va_dump() output.

Comment: @FirstOne the three arrays are three different arrays like `array(0=>6)`, `array(0=>6)` and `array(0=>4)`

Comment: you can see this question also i have this problem pleas read it and help me [my problem is explained in this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213449/retrieve-specific-field-value-for-every-menu-items-in-nav-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have an array like this,

```
$val = array(
    0 => array("6"),
    1 => array("6"),
    2 => array("4")
);
```

So to merge the array elements and rearrange the indices, you can do something like this:

```
foreach($val as $key => $array){
    $val[$key] = $array[0];
}

var_dump($val);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '6' (length=1)
  1 => string '6' (length=1)
  2 => string '4' (length=1)
```

Comment: in this case the `$val` contains three arrays but the array number in `$val` it's change means i know use your way but as i say the array numbers may be change from three array to 4 or 5 etc... i want the code collect all theme in one array and indexed them from zero to last index

Comment: @TreAhmad Yes, this code will work in those cases also. Did you test this code?

Comment: i have three different arrays

Comment: you can see this question also i have this problem pleas read it and help me [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213449/retrieve-specific-field-value-for-every-menu-items-in-nav-menu)

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why Edgar's answer is downvoited -

```
print_r(array_merge($val[0], $val[0],$val[0]));
```

gets result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 6
)
```

Comment: I was about to suggest a code to his suggestion.. This should work for any number of arrays inside the outer array (copy + 'pasteable' for testing): `$foo = array(array('foo'), array('bar'), array('something'), array('v1'), array('v2'));
$bar = array();
foreach($foo as $v){
 $bar = array_merge($bar, $v);
};
var_dump($bar);` _(Feel free to add that to your answer, if you will :) @splash58)_

Comment: I was thinking exactly that

Comment: in this case the `$val` contains three arrays but the array number in `$val` it's change means i know use your way but as i say the array numbers may be change from three array to 4 or 5 etc... i want the code collect all theme in one array and indexed them from zero to last index

Comment: look the first comment to my answer

Comment: @FirstOne ok sen to me

Comment: you can see this question also i have this problem pleas read it and help me [read this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213449/retrieve-specific-field-value-for-every-menu-items-in-nav-menu)

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using a numeric key array you could use php array_merge function to achieve exactly that